# Set value to edit grid in Extjs

Tags: extjs, datagridview, editor

I have one edit grid panel where i have all the records. I took 2 textfields on the same form. I want to set quantity value directly to the record whose id will match to the textfield value.

Any suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

This should more or less work.

```
var i = someTxtField.value();
editGrid.getStore().data.items[i]['somevalue'] = "fooBar";
editGrid.doLayout();
```